# SonarToGerrit plugin, how to get use it for multi module project

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube-scan, sonar-gerrit

I have used the sonarToGerrit plugin for a while and now I looking into how I can improve the performance when the preview mode is removed. I'm testing at the moment with latest LTS version 7.9.2 of sonarqube togheter with the branch plugin. But the problem I have at the moment is the SonarToGerrit plugin, I found there is property called subJobConfigs, And in the example in below link I understand it as I should either configure subJobConfigs or baseConfig. But the plugin fails with the error, "No SonarQube report available. Please check your Project Settings" and then it tries to access the default report path "target/sonar/sonar-report.json"

https://plugins.jenkins.io/sonar-gerrit/

Have anyone used property subJobConfigs and managed to get this working?

/Martin

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and I was able to get the subJobConfigs working as expected by also setting the `type: "multi"` property in the `inspectionConfig` object:

```
sonarToGerrit(
    inspectionConfig: [
         serverURL: "http://....",
         type: "multi",
         subJobConfigs: [
             [
                 projectPath: "submoduleA",
                 sonarReportPath: "submoduleA/path/to/report"
             ],
             [
                 projectPath: "submoduleB",
                 sonarReportPath: "submoduleB/path/to/report"
             ],
         ]
     ],
     reviewConfig: [
         issueFilterConfig: [
         severity: "MINOR",
         newIssuesOnly: true,
         changedLinesOnly: false
         ]
     ],
     scoreConfig: [
     issueFilterConfig: [
         severity: "MAJOR",
         newIssuesOnly: true,
         changedLinesOnly: false
     ],
     category: "Sonar-Review",
     noIssuesScore: +1,
     issuesScore: -1
])
```

(I was expecting `submoduleA` and `submoduleB` to be prepended to their respective `sonarReportPath`s, but I found that I had to prepend them myself.)